# Can I use Firebase Functions Emulator with GCP Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a GCP project that uses node.js javascript Google Cloud Functions that are triggered by Pub/Sub topics.

When setting up local testing according to [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/local-development), it seems quite complicated.

Using Firebase PubSub emulator and Firebase Functions emulator seems much easier. Can I just use the Firebase Functions Emulator with my GCP Cloud Functions?

Answer (score 1):

No. You can only use the Firebase emulator with functions written using the firebase-functions node module and deployed with the Firebase CLI.  It will not work any other way.

The ease of use is part of the value of using the Firebase tools over the core GCP tools, but you do have to choose to use them, as they are not interchangeable.